# Trying to create a high score of the fastest time for my HTML game

Tags: javascript, time, measure

So I'm making this reaction game where the player has to click a box as fast as possible. I've displayed the time taken to click the box but I'm trying to displayed the fastest time the player has clicked a box. I would really appreciate your help.

Here's my code:

```
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Your time: <span id="time"></span></p>
        <p>Highscore: <span id="highscore"></span></p>
        <div id="shape"></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var start = new Date().getTime();
        function makeShapeAppear() {
            document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "block"
            start = new Date().getTime();
        }
        function appearAfterDelay() {
            setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, 1000);
        }
        appearAfterDelay();
        document.getElementById("shape").onclick = function() {
            var end = new Date().getTime();
            var timeTaken = (end - start)/1000;
            document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s";
            appearAfterDelay();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

To summarize, I want to display the shortest "timeTaken" variable in the highscore id. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you give a codepen link?

Comment: You haven't specified an actual problem regarding the code shown. You mentioned a goal but that doesn't tell us what does or doesn't work within your code. Take a few minutes to read [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your last time taken if no highscore, if the new time taken is less than your highscore then set the highscore to be the timetaken. Like this.

```css
#shape{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <p>Your time:
      <span id="time"></span>
    </p>
    <p>Highscore:
      <span id="highscore"></span>
    </p>
    <div id="shape"></div>
  </div>
  <script>
    var highscore;
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    function makeShapeAppear() {
      document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "block"
      start = new Date().getTime();
    }
    function appearAfterDelay() {
      setTimeout(makeShapeAppear, 1000);
    }
    appearAfterDelay();
    document.getElementById("shape").onclick = function () {
      var end = new Date().getTime();
      var timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;
      highscore = (timeTaken < highscore || !highscore ? timeTaken : highscore);
      document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s";
      document.getElementById("highscore").innerHTML = highscore + "s";
      appearAfterDelay();
    }
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: That worked beautifully. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using cookies. Each time the user clicks the box, check if cookie exists, if not create one with time value. If it does exist compare its value to current one and depending on if it is lower update the cookies value.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show "the fastest time **the player** (singular) has clicked a box" and you want to keep that value **despite user close and open the browser or tab** you could use localStorage or sessionStorage.

```
localStorage.setItem("bestTime", timeTaken);
```

and

```
var bestTime = localStorage.getItem("bestTime");

if(timeTaken > bestTime){
localStorage.setItem("bestTime", timeTaken);
}
```

This approach stores the info in the browser.  If you want to store the fastest time **players** (plural) have clicked or save the data to use in different browsers, you need to use a database storage.